# In Django I want to fetch the selected file name file is in my media folder so I want to fetch it and display it in html that the file is selected

Tags: python, html, django, database

This is my html code for update the form I have the uploaded file through a html form and the pdf file is getting stored in my media folder and the file name in database, so like the text fields I also want to retrieve the selected file from the media folder the  value ="{{i.cv}}" is not working like I did it in text fields so basically I have two html one is for
filling up where there is also file field am uploading pdf files in it and it is storing in media folder  another html for updating the data in there the upload cv does not select any file what's the solution for this.
this is my html

```
       <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black">Upload CV</label></br>
          <input type="file"  name="cv" id="cv1" value ="{{i.cv}}">
        </div>
      </div>
```

here is models.py

```
class ApplyForm(models.Model):      
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

this is views.py

```
def update(request, id):
    i.cv = request.FILES['cv']
```

I just want the file to be selected during edit I am uploading pdf files

Comment: You should use a Form or ModelForm for handling forms, the forms.FileField widget already handles this. You cannot have a file initially "selected" when editing, files are always user provided

Comment: Is it not possible in html forms I have already created and I dont want to do in model forms.